# Android drag recycler view from bottom over map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, layout, android-viewpager, fragment

I would like to immitate google street view layout.
I have a viewpager with a single map. I would like to display a recycler on the bottom of each page, and drag + scroll it from bottom.
Here is the desired result (I don't need to hide the action bar) :

[image]

Would you know which layout to use in order to have the same drag / scroll from bottom effect?

I managed to have a single map for myviewpager :

[image]

but when I add the recyclerView in my viewpager fragments, it obviously hide the map :

[image]

Right now my tab fragment is only composed by the recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_topic_list" />
```

I tried to use a bottom sheet but it was catching the map event, and I was unable to control the scroll (inertia).

Comment: you can use this library for drag recycler view from bottom over map fragment https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html

Comment: The problem with a bottom sheet fragment is that I cannot control the drag. It is either in closed or opened state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom Sheets are a lesser known part of the Design support library. The Design support library is an Android library intended to help android developers implement the Google material design guidelines.

Bottom sheets can be dragged up and down. You need to explore it more. I can point you toward some helpful resource. You should follow them. I really think they can help you.

Clone this plaid app's [repo](https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid) and study the code. It is using bottom sheet in it with drag and drop

Also follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/) it will help you to understand the behavior of bottom sheet

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the resources. This is what I needed.